# Configuring Tomcat server for windows

Tags: tomcat

I have installed apache-tomcat-6.0.35-windows-x86 in my system. How can I configure it and set class path properly?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to set anything.  Tomcat ignores your `CLASSPATH` environment variable, as do all Java EE app servers.  Just start it up with the startup script in the `/bin` directory.

Comment: ok..thank you..but while searching i got so many videos and tutorials regarding this configuring and setting path...that's y i got confused..

Comment: After installing i got 'configure tomcat' in the start menu,as i click on it it shows an error message that 'Access is denied. Unable to open the service Tomcat6'..In the icon which had come in the tray also shows configure in bold..so what i have to do next?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set anything. Tomcat ignores your CLASSPATH environment variable, as do all Java EE app servers. Just start it up with the startup script in the /bin directory.

Does this also applicable to Linux server.??

Answer (score 0):

If you actually did want to set the classpath for some reason, setclasspath.bat is used to set the classpath for any of the running process when launched from a batch file.

when launched from a service, you can set the classpath by running:
bin\tomcat#w.exe where # is the version of Tomcat you're running.

That will popup a user interface that will let you set many items for your Tomcat service.